# Firebase.setAndroidContext(Context) causes FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Tags: android, firebase

Just by calling this method `Firebase.setAndroidContext(this)`(the first thing to do in order to work with Firebase) anywhere on my application causes an `FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1`

I am running `'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.1.1+'` on Gradle.

The funny thing is, the demo application they provide works! and the code is exactly the same as mine!
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-login-demo-android

So, can anyone help me here?

Here is the full stack:

```
    01-26 05:48:00.142  14666-14693/br.com.vymajoris.helpradarprototype1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: br.com.vymajoris.helpradarprototype1, PID: 14666
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Object.hashCode()' on a null object reference
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:911)
        at com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:673)
        at com.facebook.widget.LoginButton$1.doInBackground(LoginButton.java:678)
        at com.facebook.widget.LoginButton$1.doInBackground(LoginButton.java:675)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
```

Comment: If everyone who said "that code is the same as mine" were correct, we would have a lot less bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to help without any code to work with. But did you pass the application context?

Create a class (like in the example) called **LoginDemoApplication**:

```
public class LoginDemoApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    }
}
```

Then in the AndroidManifest.xml under the application tag add:

```
android:name=".LoginDemoApplication"
```

And then you can create your Firebase reference in your Activity like normal:

```
Firebase mFirebaseRef = new Firebase("your_firebase_url);
```

**EDIT:**

In your mainfests application tag, make sure you have

```
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```

With the value beeing the AppID of the corresponding app at developers.facebook.com

Comment: I didn't posted any code because the code you posted is the code I am using! Anyway, I created another project and it is working with the new project. Thanks for your time   ps. I would close this question, but I'll leave it open in case someone has an explanation.

Comment: See if the EDIT helps out any? In the project that fails.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick! How weird though... I didn't added that meta-data tag because I was doing the Google login first! However, I will only be able to test the full auth process later this day. But I believe it will work just fine. If anything goes wrong, I'll post here.

Comment: Facebook SDK uses an app id to query the Graph API for the app settings, and this id is read from the manifest. If you dont supply it, the graph api call will return null and result in your NullPointerException. Glad I could help - now back to work! :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to change

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
```

to

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this.getApplication());
```

and that fixed it.